# Want to use OPENROWSET to open Local XML file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, openrowset

I'm doing some testing in SSMS with various XML files on my LOCAL disk (in my C:\Temp folder), but I am connected to a remote test SQL Server.  Is there any way to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @xml xml

-- Want to read from my local, but this attempts to read from the SQL Server's C drive
SELECT @xml = CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

-- Insert into table on the remote SQL Server
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (StatementType, OperatingDate, StatementAmount)
SELECT  doc.col.value('(StatementType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') StatementType
     ,doc.col.value('(OperatingDate)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') OperatingDate
     ,doc.col.value('(StatementAmount)[1]', 'numeric(12,2)') StatementAmount
FROM @xml.nodes('/Level1/Level2') doc(col)
```

I've searched for the answer to this, but have not found it.  And yes, I know I could create a test SQL Server locally on my machine, and no, I don't have access to copy the test XML files onto the SQL Server machine.  But really, I just want to know if there's any way to do what I am asking.

Comment: No - the path refers to the disk **local to the machine where SQL Server is running**. If SQL Server runs on a remote machine, it **CANNOT** access your own `C:\` drive ....

Comment: Just to complement @marc_s comment. Usually a UNC file share is created for such scenario to hold files. SQL Server instance account is given access to that UNC file share as well as any required user account. Such setup satisfies all the needs.

Comment: You could perhaps use blob storage

Comment: Why not map a drive to a shared UNC path on a file server, or create a share on the SQL Server and copy the file there.

Comment: Seems strange that I could do this:

SET @xml = '<Level1><Level2>test1</Level2><Level2>test2</Level2></Level1>';

but I can't read from an XML file on my local drive, which basically does the same thing.

Comment: Do you **really** want some remote server to be able to access your own local `C:\\` drive and read files from it? Think about that ...

Comment: No, I don't.  But I want to be able to pull an XML file from my local disk into an XML variable.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Why not just parameterize the query like you're supposed to?

Comment: @Charlieface, it is not about parameters. SQL Server instance cannot see user's drives

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I know, I'm saying the solution is to use the *client* who can see the file, to load it in via a parameter, rather than trying to mess around with UNC shares (which are difficult to get working with local service accounts, and have security risks if just opened to Everyone).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server can only bulk load from a drive it has access to. Unless you somehow connect the client's drive to the server (probably a bad idea) it won't work.

Instead, you can use Powershell to send the data via a parameterized query. `Invoke-SqlCmd` doesn't work well with parameters, you should use the DbaTools `Invoke-DbaQuery` instead

```
$xml = Get-Content -Path "C:\SomePath" -Raw;
$xmlParam = New-DbaSqlParameter -ParameterName "@xml" -SqlDbType Xml -SqlValue $xml;

Invoke-DbaQuery `
  -SqlInstance ".\SQLEXPRESS" `
  -SqlParameter $xml `
  -Query @"
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
  (StatementType, OperatingDate, StatementAmount)
SELECT
  doc.col.value('(StatementType  /text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  doc.col.value('(OperatingDate  /text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  doc.col.value('(StatementAmount/text())[1]', 'numeric(12,2)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/Level1/Level2') doc(col);
"@;
```

Comment: Yes @Charlieface, this is similar to what I wanted, but it is not done within SSMS.  It gave me an idea though, that solved my problem.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Only if u are in a protected network try this.
Share a folder on your computer and put there your file.
Grant access to this folder to everyone.

In the query aim to your pc \yourpc\folderwithonlyonefile\file.xml

Lmk!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not on a protected network.

Comment: So, avoid it. Exposing your share could happen everything. No other ways to exchange "file" between you and the server.
U can't reach it's file system and it couldn't reach your file system.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is only testing on my local machine as mentioned, I have no problem accessing the local file system.  Thus, this is a solution that worked fine for me.

```
EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
EXECUTE sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #xmlfile;
CREATE TABLE #xmlfile ([xmldata] NVARCHAR(max));

DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(50) = 'TYPE "C:\temp\test.xml"';
DECLARE @xmlstring NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @xml XML;

-- Insert the file's data into the temp table
INSERT INTO #xmlfile EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Cmd; 
SELECT @xmlstring = COALESCE(@xmlstring, '') + xmldata FROM #xmlfile  -- get all rows into a string
SET @xml = CONVERT(xml, @xmlstring);  -- convert string to xml and store in variable

-- Output @xml to test
SELECT  doc.col.value('(StatementType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') StatementType
     ,doc.col.value('(OperatingDate)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') OperatingDate
     ,doc.col.value('(StatementAmount)[1]', 'numeric(12,2)') StatementAmount
FROM @xml.nodes('/Level1/Level2') doc(col)
```

**UPDATE**
Not working as expected.  I was accidently attached to my local DB in the window I tested this.  Instead, I want to be in a window attached to my remote DB.

Comment: This also doesn't work if the file is not on the same machine as the SQL Server, so it's no better than your original in that respect (and as far as security is substantially worse as you have to enable shell access).

Comment: @Charlieface - Yes, you are correct.  See my update above.